# OpenCV not working Correctly - Face Recognition

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am currently writing a script for face recognition. However, it doesn't appear to be functioning properly and I cannot find the bug.

I am trying to get it to loop a given number of times dependent upon the user input it receives. Then it will take the picture of that person, if it recognizes their face then save it will save it to an array and then iterate again, repeating this process.

It appears to be saving the last picture the it took.

Example: I smile in the first picture, it saves this one correctly and puts into array. Next, I have a straight face, and it, but instead of saving this face, it saves the smile from before and adds this image to the array. Finally, I close my eyes in the next picutre and it saves a straight face picture and adds it to the array.

Here is the relevant code:

```
from SimpleCV import *

people = raw_input('How many people are going to be recognized?: ')

names = []
faceDatabase = []

picTaken = False
firstStageDone = False;

img = None
face = None
faces = None

cam = Camera()

def reset(img, face, faces):
    img = None
    face = None
    faces = None

while firstStageDone is False:
    for i in range(0, int(people)):
        picTaken = False
        reset(img,face,faces)

        while picTaken is False:
            takePic = raw_input('When ready type something: ')
            image = cam.getImage().show()
            img = cam.getImage()
            faces = img.findHaarFeatures('face.xml')
            if faces:
                print 'Face Detected!'
                print 'Length of Array ' + str(len(faceDatabase))
                print 'Current Index ' + str(i)
                faces.draw()
                face = faces[-1]
                face.crop().save('face' + str(i) + '.jpg')
                faceDatabase.append(face.crop())
                personName = raw_input('What is your name?: ')
                names.append(personName)
                print 'Index of ' + personName + ' is ' + str(i)
                faceDatabase[i].save(names[i] + ".jpg")
                picTaken = True
            else:
                print 'Try Again No Face Found'
            faces = None
            img = None
    firstStageDone = True
```

I appreciate any assistance that can be offered.

Comment: Are you sure it's the program is recognizing faces properly? If the program's thinking your chin is your face (or any other image you toss to it), then that could be the problem (in which case you'll want to play with the face.xml file).

Comment: It is the actual program because its saving everything that it is recognizing, and its not recognizing the chin its recognizing 'face.xml'